# Verification pins for new users

Tags: email

We need to change the email address for where the verification pins for new users are sent. The existing email address is an ex employee

Comment: Are you trying to reuse an old user? You should not be doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Those are sent to the new users directly, not to an existing user.

You should not be trying to re-use old users. Deactivating a user frees up the license for re-use so that you do not need to purchase a new license.

If you attempt to change a user's email, a verification email is sent to the old address to verify the change before it updates in Salesforce meaning you can't just change the email.

**What not to do:**

Lastly, if you decide not to listen to everything I said above, you can follow the below:

1. Go to the user whos email you want to change
2. Click **Edit**
3. Modify the **email address**
4. scroll all the way to the bottom and select the **Generate new
   password and notify user immediately** box.
5. Click **Save**

That should reset the email without a verification and allow the password to be changed. The owner of the new email will receive the password reset email. **But ya know, don't do it this way. Deactivate the old user and create a new one**.